# Difference between float and decimal in Oracle and t-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, floating-point, decimal

I have selected same query in Oracle and t-sql, I am little confused

answers is on the contrary.

(I am interested in difference between float and decimal)

Some explanations?

T-sql:

```
DECLARE @A decimal(30,20);   
DECLARE @b float(10);


set @A=100
set @b=100

select 
  @A/3 + @A/3 + @A/3 as decimal,
  @b/3 + @b/3 + @b/3 as float
```

Oracle:

```
Declare flt Float;
        dcm Decimal(30,20);

Begin

  flt:=100;
  dcm:=100;

  flt:=flt/3+flt/3+flt/3;
  dcm:=dcm/3+dcm/3+dcm/3;

  dbms_output.put_line(flt);
  dbms_output.put_line(dcm);

End;
```

Comment: It is easy to identify if you post sample query or data in text format instead of image.

Comment: I wrote codes, you can check it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLOAT in computer science are approximate value, you can read this : [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=1)

Decimal value in TSQL are like 2 integer with a dot between, so its the exact value but require more space.
I will always recommand you to work with decimal value in database.

Comment: if float is approximate value, why does it gives me different result in T-sql and oracle?

Comment: @VasoMiruashvili - "approximate" means *not exact". So it is not surprising that different platforms with different implementations produce values which are approximately but not exactly the same.